# como encontrar a el nombre de usuario con solo su id

Tags: nodejs, discord.js

soy nuevo en esto, y no se como implementarlo, estuve buscando en [la documentación de discord](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User?scrollTo=id)
pero no encontré nada, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer esto, hay unas condiciones que deben cumplirse:

1. El usuario este disponible para el bot, esto significa que tengan algo en común, como un servidor.
2. El ID sea un identificador válido, si no existe ese identificador o no es válido habrá un error.

Si esas condiciones se cumplen podrás hacerlo, te incluyo un ejemplo.

```
// Si aún no has creado tu bot. ---

const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ 
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]
});

client.login('El token de tu bot aquí.');

//--------------------------------

client.once('ready', async () => {
  try {
    // Almacenamos el usuario en una variable.
    const user = await client.users.fetch('user-id-aqui');
    
    // mostramos por consola el tag del usuario, si es que existe.
    if (user && user.tag) console.log('Usuario encontrado!:', user.tag);
  } catch (error) { // en caso de haber un error, lo mostrará por consola.
    console.log('Error:', error);
  }
});
```

### En resumen

El usar `client.users.fetch('user-id')` o `client.users.cache.get('user-id')` retornará un objeto tipo [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User), si este existe o si está disponible para el bot.

Espero sea de tu ayuda.